# Django CreateView dynamic fields form for model with ManyToMany through

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have model with few ManyToManyFields all using through (custom intermediate table) and I want to create using CreateView. Problem is that I get form without ability to create data for intermediate table.

Answer (score 2):

well you can create an intermedicate table entry directy, and then u can add it to the many to many field, for example

```
modelObject = YourModel.objects.create(.....)
intermedicateObject = IntermediateModel.objects.create(.....)
modelObject.M2MfieldName.add(intermedicateObject)
```